# Passing asp.net login name to the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, logging, credentials

I'm wondering how to solve the following issue:

I have a web asp.net app where Forms Authentification is used, connected to the Active Directory. Also, I have a connection string to MS SQL db in the web app, where one global user (with given privileges) is used. The problem is that when I want to store information about the user (e.g. data modification log) in database, I can only get the global user info provided in the connection string, not the real user who is logged in.

Is there any possiblity to log onto a web app with my personal credentials, after, use a global user credentials to connect into the database and pass my personal user credentials (but not as parameters in store procedure) that database will think that the user who is logged in is not the global user?

I assume, it might be only possible if I also create same users in the database and use Impersonalization?

Or any other possibillities?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing to get the current user? Are you doing something like `SELECT @user = SYSTEM_USER`? This will obviously only return the user that you connect to SQL Server with.

I would rather keep to using a single SQL login that the application uses, but pass in the username when you are making changes, e.g. through a sproc or a table update:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomething
    @id INT,
    @username VARCHAR(50)
AS
    -- Make your changes.

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Audit] SELECT 'update', @id, @username
GO
```

In ASP.NET you can grab the currently logged in user through `User.Identity.Name` property of the page.

Comment: Ye, I'm using the standard ways how to get the user connected to the SQL Server instance. However, the solution with passing the real username as a parameter is not available for me. I would like to use MS SQL 2008 Auditing Services to log all changes and there is no possibility how to pass the username as a parameter (at least I'm not aware of it). The best would be if the web app could authentificate the user and tell to the DB, "yes, user Frankie is ok, let him to connect to the db with rights of GlobalUser, and remember his name as Frankie"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a role within your database to handle permissions, and then get the users you need in a group in AD, and assign permissions to that AD group to access your database under the role you define.  (This way you don't need to assign each user to your database as you create them).

You would then use windows authentication right the way through from your web site to the database, and have the user identity that you need for logging. (You'll need to set identity impersonate="true" in your configuration).

I would note that this is only going to work (easily) if your servers and your users are all on the same network.